# Use cell value to activate another sheet then clear original cell value without an error

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have cell A1 on a sheet named "Data" that looks for input which when received, looks for a sheet name that matches it. If it finds a match, it opens that sheet. I'm trying to clear the value entered in A1 of "Data" after that second sheet has been opened however I'm getting a runtime error that appears to still be looking for the data used to open the second sheet. Here is the code for the "Data" sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Sheets(Target.Value).Activate
End Sub
```

I tried using a variable in place of Target.Value hoping that after deleting the actual data in A1, the variable would satisfy the code.

I've ran the following line on at the end of the block above as well as on the sheet which gets activated but either way I get an error.

```
Sheets("Data").Range("A1:A1").ClearContents
```

The error is "Run-time error 9 Subscript out of range.

How do I clear the contents of A1 on "Data" so it's ready to receive another request to open another sheet when I'm done with the last one?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax for a single cell:

```
Sheets("Data").Range("A1").ClearContents
```

...however using a range of `A1:A1` should also work, so if you're getting `Subscript Out Of Range` then there is likely no worksheet named `Data`.

If you have multiple workbooks open then by default, it's looking for the Active Workbook (whose name in contained in `ActiveWorkbook.Name`.)  So if you're going to be working with multiple workbooks, you should explicitly state the workbook name as well:

```
Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").ClearContents
```

Comment: Still get the error. Only working with one workbook.

Comment: When you clear the cell you initiate a worksheet change, and the code runs again, it then tries to find a no name worksheet. you need to put error handling in your code.

Comment: Do you have a worksheet named `Data`?  ...also, if you used my last example, how did you change it for your workbook?

Comment: @Driver8 -- What are you trying to do?  It looks like you want to clear 'A1' as soon as anything is typed in it? That doesn't make sense...  (`Target` returns the cell that was changed.)

Comment: @ashleedawg Just went back to make sure and yes, I do. It is also displayed at the top of the code window.

Comment: @GMalc has the right idea, I hadn't considered it. Now to figure out how to properly handle the empty cell.

Comment: @Driver8 Empty cells shouldn't matter - as long as you're not doing something illogical.  Can you explain a little more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ashleedawg Taking the value in A1 and using it to identify a sheet to open. I then need A1 to be cleared for the next entry. Although as I type this I'm thinking that leaving the value alone and just making sure A1 is always the active cell when the page opens would mean that value would get over-written the next time I need it which would work also. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would it get overwritten?  Also, it doesn't matter what the active cell is, since with VBA you can always specify a location when reading/writing/etc.

Comment: I believe this is what's known as an **[X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)**.   I have a feeling that you're getting bogged down by the "Y" instead of properly designing/debugging the "X".    You need to back waaay up and explain what the end-goal is (ie., *Why* do you need to open a workbook based on the value of a A1?  *Why & how* is A1 getting populated in the first place?  *What kind* of data is in these workbooks? etc etc) No offence intended, of course! :-)   (It's very common and a fresh set of eyes can help.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight change to your code. "Is Nothing" does not work. The below code works fine for me.

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) = "" Then Exit Sub
Sheets(Target.Value).Activate
Target.ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need to clear the value after all. I added a couple lines to ensure when returning to the "Data" sheet, cell A1 was selected. This allows for a new value to be entered replacing the previous value and serves the purpose.